# Retrieve client id for pipeline service principal in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

In my Azure Pipeline (YAML), I am deploying an ARM template to create a key vault (among other resources), then running a PowerShell script to generate a certificate and store it in the key vault. This gives me a `Forbidden` error. In [Use secrets from Azure Key Vault in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops#set-up-azure-key-vault-access-policies), Microsoft suggests that I need to create an access policy on the key vault for the pipeline service principal. When I do this, the script succeeds.

[image: Service connections]
*Image from [cache404](https://cache404.net/tutorial-azure-devops-pipeline-accessing-secrets-from-azure-key-vault/)*

I would now like to create this access policy programmatically as part of the ARM template, but I don't know how to retrieve the object id for the pipeline service principal programmatically within the pipeline. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst Hugh Lin's answer is valid, I found it simpler to adapt [Nick Graham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58820706/14207973) for granting key vault access to the pipeline service principal as part of the PowerShell script itself:

```
$Context = Get-AzContext
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultName -ServicePrincipalName $Context.Account.Id -PermissionsToCertificates Get,List,Create
```

Comment: Thanks @HughLin-MSFT; same to you!

Comment: Thank you.  It helped me as well .. i had exactly problem

Answer (score 1):

> I would now like to create this access policy programmatically as part
> of the ARM template, but I don't know how to retrieve the object id
> for the pipeline service principal programmatically within the
> pipeline.

If you want to automatically obtain the service principal object ID in the ARM template, I am afraid this is impossible.

You can try to create a script(`Get-AzADServicePrincipal`) to get the service principal and pass it to the arm template.

Here is the [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308250/azure-arm-template-add-deployer-object-id-to-key-vault-access-policies) with similar issue you can refer to.